# Email data from spreadsheet if a specific value is filled

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to get an email when the sheet is edited but only if a specific column has a specific value. In that case I would like to get data from the whole row that was edited.

I found and tried this solution whit a trigger that sends me an email every time the sheet is edited and it works:

```
function onEdit2(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
var editedCell =  ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnEnd, 1, 1);      
var body = "FYI Cell: " + editedCell.getA1Notation()+ " was changed to: "+ editedCell.getValue(); 
MailApp.sendEmail("exa...@email.com", "Edit report", body); 
}
```

But I don't know how to set it to work with my conditions. I thought something like:

`if( e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value == 'OK' )`....but than what??

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have your own answer... ;-)

```
if( e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value == 'OK' ){MailApp.sendEmail("exa...@email.com", "Edit report", body)};
```

Use the condition to execute the 'mail' part...

I would eventually add a column to show a mail has been sent to avoid duplicates, something like in in [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails#section2), or change the background color of the cell for which a mail has been sent... your choice.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what was the problem. I use data validation in column 7, and every time I edit the sheet using value from the drop down list (data validation) I don't get any email (or error notification either). But if I type the resired value (which is in validation list) than it works great and I get the email. I don't know if that's a known issue, a bug or something? Is anyone else familiar with that?